# Jquery validation plugins including file validation and dynamic fields

Tags: jquery, angularjs, validation

I am creating dynamic form elements by using ng-repeat in angular js, it also contains file upload fields. I need to validate those fields. Is their any plugin for validating those fields

Comment: What kind of validation do you need? Mabe this one: https://jqueryvalidation.org/extension-method/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularJS offers client-side form validation.

http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_validation.asp